# Removing 'white sticker' on PCB

Tags: pcb, reverse-engineering

I want to reverse engineer the circuit from an insect swatter. However, there is this 'white sticker' at the back of the circuit. I am assuming this is for some kind of protection or just to hide the circuit. Is it safe to remove this? And what tools/methods can I use if it can be removed? Thank you.[image: Insect Swatter circuit]

Comment: That looks more like silkscreen than a sticker to me

Comment: Seconding @PlasmaHH's questino: are you *sure* this is a sticker and not something printed onto the PCB, like for example the "HV-" and "HV+" text at the bottom?

Comment: I reckon that silk screen is doubling as something to inhibit surface moisture, which could make the HV track across the board., maybe.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure hence I dubbed it as a 'white sticker' I think it is not silkscreen since from the basics that have been taught in my electronics course, silkscreens are commonly used for labels/text. I am currently, researching for circuits with these on board.

Comment: @TheBlackViper Silkscreen can be used for drawing anything, whether it be labels/text, blocks, logos, or entire filled areas. My bet is that it is indeed silkscreen and is used to help insulate the low voltage side of the board from the high voltage side

Comment: @TheBlackViper -- If you're not sure if it is 'x', please don't call it 'x'.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to see the traces to reverse-engineer it, try shining a bright light behind it. You may be able to see the traces as shadows/silhouette.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments state you need to confirm whether this is a sticker or printed silkscreen on the PCB, the photo isn't high enough resolution to say really and I haven't seen anything like it before. First of all are you planning on re-using it, if so I wouldn't touch it.

If it is a sticker then you should be able to pick at a corner to lift it off the PCB with a decent pair of tweezers. If you can't just peel it off easily then soak in IPA (isopropyl alcohol), this should help to dissolve the adhesive without damaging the board or any plastic components. Note you sould take care about what parts you soak in IPA - buzzers and batteries are a no no, but assuming there aren't any of these parts fitted and you're not reusing the board this shouldn't matter anyway.

If it isn't a silkscreen then you may be able to remove using acetone (nail varnish remover if you don't have access to any pure stuff) but this could also remove the solder resist (green coating on the PCB) depending on what it's made of. Definatley don't do this if you are planning on re-using the board.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the silk screen / sticker could be used to isolate the two HV lines. High Voltages? That could prevent short circuits from things like water and moisture (and your hands).

If it is a sticker, if is a little weird that they didn't covered the 2 pins themselves but I guess it's China...

Others have already mentioned ways to remove it so I won't repeat their anwsers.

Comment: A careful look at the photo shows a few air bubbles between sticker and board - silkscreen doesn't do that. Looks like a cheap substitute for conformal coating . "HV" pins are far apart, so don't need protection quite so much.